# Setting Java path on Windows for Ant

Tags: ant

Just downloaded the latest version of Ant and installed at:

```
C:\apache-ant-1.8.4
```

I added the following to the Env Path variable:

```
...;C:\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin
```

When I open a terminal window and type:

```
ant -version
```

I get:

```
Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07"" was unexpected at this time.
```

In System variables I have the variable JAVA_HOME set to:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07"
```

so it appears that "ant -version" is struggling to read the space in JAVA_HOME even though it is in quotes.

I see an alternative post on this topic:

[Ant and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697044/ant-and-eclipse)

but it doesn't tackle this specific point.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and know the answer?

Answer (score 15):

My guess is current definition of JAVA_HOME has unwanted double quotes.   Show output of `set JAVA_HOME` on command window. It should not have any double quotes.

Please start command prompt. Set the JAVA_HOME again

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, it should be fine with quotes.  Could be something else in your path.  If all else fails you could revert to dos 8.3 notation.

```
dir /x
```

Which gives

```
13/01/2013  03:57 PM    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
13/01/2013  03:57 PM    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is still encountering this problem, I am on Windows 7 and was experiencing the same. I was using the GUI provided by right-clicking the "computer" icon to attempt to set the JAVA_HOME path to the relevant program files folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45). This will not work! The GUI doesn't accept spaces in paths. Command line however, does. Use set JAVA_HOME= C:\Program Files... to get it working, filling out the rest of the path with the location of your jdk installation.