# "Files was unexpected at this time" apache ant

Tags: ant

my java_home and ant_home folder is okey and my environmental variables is okey but I got this error how can I solve this problem?

thank you for your helps

Comment: you should also set your PATH variable as described [here](https://www.mkyong.com/ant/how-to-install-apache-ant-on-windows/)

Comment: already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14432798/524900)

Comment: my problem has been solved by me. 

my java classpath and "qtjava.zip" folder was wrong in the environmental variables.I change these folders correct directory and my problem has solved.